# Using foreach loop through array in an array using php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, stdclass

I am fairly new to PHP and have been working on looping through this array for *days*...sigh...

http://pastebin.com/Rs6P4e4y

I am trying to get the name and headshot values of the writers and directors array.

I've been trying to figure out the foreach function to use with it, but have had no luck.

```
<?php   foreach ($directors as $key => $value){
            //print_r($value);
        }
?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `->` to access properties of the objects.

```
foreach ($directors as $director) {
    echo 'Name: ' . $director->name . "\n";
    echo "Headshot: " . $director->images->headshot . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You looking for some such beast?  You didn't write how you wanted to process them, but hopefully this helps you.

```
$directors = array();

foreach( $object->people->directors as $o )
    $directors[] = array( 'name' => $o->name, 'headshot' => $o->images->headshot );

$writers = array();

foreach( $object->people->writers as $o )
    $writers[] = array( 'name' => $o->name, 'headshot' => $o->images->headshot );

var_dump( $directors );
var_dump( $writers );
```

Last note, if there's no guarantee that these members are set, you use `isset` before any dirty work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution has already been posted, but I want to add something:

This isn't an Array, it's an object. Actually the directors property of the object is an Array. Look up what an object is and what associative arrays are!

Objects have properties, arrays have keys and values.

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->something = 'this is an object property';

$array = new array();
$array['something'] = 'this is an array key named something';

$object->arrayproperty = $array;
echo $object->arrayproperty['something']; //this is an array key named something
```

Good luck with learning PHP! :)

Answer (score 0):

Having variable `$foo`, which is an object, you can access property `bar` using syntax:

```
$foo->bar
```

So if you have an array od directors named `$directors`, you can simply use it the same way in `foreach`:

```
foreach ($directors as $value){
   echo $value->name." ".$value->images->headshot;
}
```

Comment: Kind of confusing to use the variable `$key` for the values, not keys.